# Minimum spec requirements for a phone for Android development

Tags: android

To be a bit more specific to my case, I'm new to Android development, and I want an Android phone to properly test apps on. This phone would only be used for development, since I already have an iPhone for general use.

It only needs to be powerful enough to test small apps and 2D/3D games (I will likely upgrade in the future). My computer is pretty good, so I don't need to worry about my computer specs.

I'm not asking "which phone should I get", I already have one specific phone I want to buy, since it's on sale. I'm just unsure if it will be powerful enough. For reference, this is the phone I'm looking at: https://www.thinkofus.com.au/zte-shout-blade-a110-4g-unlocked-900-2100-3g-white

Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of people will downvote this answer but still, I will tell you that the device depends on the type of app you are building and the features you want in the app. If you are building a selfie camera app, the device needs to have a front-facing camera or if your app uses NFC the device needs NFC support. From the software point, you need to look at the Android version to see if the feature you want to develop is supported in your device. Low end device will be helpful in making a better app as you would have to worry about memory and CPU constraints, But I would suggest getting 2-3 devices of various types